# How to get err, stderr from execSync()?

Tags: node.js

In node 12, execSync can return stdout, e.g.

```
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;

const stdout = execSync('ls');
console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
```

But how to get err and stderr ?
In the callback of child_process.exec, you have all 3.

I can use async way, but prefer to use execSync() if it's easier.

Comment: I've been trying to work this out too. I know that `execSync()` throws an error when the command's exit code is not zero and you can often gather some info from that. It's also possible to define where stdio (stdout & stderr) are sent via the `stdio` option, but I haven't developed working code for this yet.

Answer (score 16):

Nodejs docs says:

> The child_process.execSync() method is generally identical to
> child_process.exec() with the exception that the method will not
> return until the child process has fully closed. When a timeout has
> been encountered and killSignal is sent, the method won't return until
> the process has completely exited. If the child process intercepts and
> handles the SIGTERM signal and doesn't exit, the parent process will
> wait until the child process has exited.
>
> **If the process times out or has a non-zero exit code, this method will
> throw. The Error object will contain the entire result from
> child_process.spawnSync() as below**

```
Returns: <Object>

pid <number> Pid of the child process.
output <Array> Array of results from stdio output.
stdout <Buffer> | <string> The contents of output[1].
stderr <Buffer> | <string> The contents of output[2].
status <number> | <null> The exit code of the subprocess, or null if the subprocess terminated due to a signal.
signal <string> | <null> The signal used to kill the subprocess, or null if the subprocess did not terminate due to a signal.
error <Error> The error object if the child process failed or timed out.
```

When method throw, the above object will be available in `catch` block as error object. For example:

```
const { execSync }=  require('child_process');

try {
  let res= execSync('ps')
   console.log("NO ERROR")
   console.log(res.toString())
   
}
catch (err){ 
  console.log("output", err)
  console.log("sdterr",err.stderr.toString())
}
```

Unlike the spawn method, it does not return the child process instance but the stdout result as a buffer. Also, check **stdio** option param to the method.

> stdio  |  Child's stdio configuration. stderr by
> default will be output to the parent process' stderr unless stdio is
> specified. Default: 'pipe'.

```
const { execSync }  = require('child_process');

try {
const result = execSync('ls . *.blah', {
  // stdio: [
  //   0, // Use parent's stdin for child.
  //   0, // use parent's stdout for child.
  //   0, // use parent's stderr for child .
  // ],
});
} catch(err){
  
}

process.stderr.on('data',()=>{
  console.log("stderr",data);
})
```

Comment: What is this answer even answering? I don't want to throw or exit "with non-zero exit code" or anything like that, I just want to get to the `stderr`. Writing to `stderr` and exiting with non-zero are completely independent activities.

Answer (score 5):

execSync Returns:  |  The stdout from the command.execSync extents  spawnSync, so you cannot catch array error message, if you want, you can use spawnSync,
https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options

```
Returns: <Object>

pid <number> Pid of the child process.
output <Array> Array of results from stdio output.
stdout <Buffer> | <string> The contents of output[1].
stderr <Buffer> | <string> The contents of output[2].
status <number> | <null> The exit code of the subprocess, or null if the subprocess terminated due to a signal.
signal <string> | <null> The signal used to kill the subprocess, or null if the subprocess did not terminate due to a signal.
error <Error> The error object if the child process failed or timed out.
```